# While calling to Web API endpoint service is throwing 524 on production server but on local throwing TaskCancelation exception

Tags: c#, http-status-codes, webapi

I read about the `524 error` code but I am curious to know the same code work differently in two environments. While testing on my local server it is throwing me `TaskCanceledException` as expected. But the same thing behaves differently on my production server. It is throwing the `524 Cloudfare error` code and my page is broken.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: The Server is failing in different part of the code.  For example the local server may find a proxy and then get the TaskCancelation exception.  While the remote server is waiting for a proxy and then timing out because the proxy isn't found.   The default timeout for a proxy is 30 seconds.

Comment: If default timeout for a proxy is 30 seconds then may be not since I am getting exception around 100 seconds for local as well as production.